# Access is Denied - IE8 Polyfills

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, localhost, access-denied

I've found similar questions to the issue I'm having, but not of them seem to resolve my particular issue.

I'm working on a website prototype that I'm hosting locally. I'm referencing JQuery, Modernizr and Respond in the head, as well as PIE.htc in the CSS as border-radius polyfill (code below):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Inquire - Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/desktop.css" />
<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/modernizr-2.0.6.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
```

CSS:

```
.button{
border-radius: 7px 7px 0 0;
border: 2px solid #00667A;
-moz-border-radius: 7px 7px 0 0;
-webkit-border-radius: 7px 7px 0 0;
background: #0CF;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#00d6ff), to(#00667A));
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #00d6FF, #00667A);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00D6FF endColorstr=#00667A);
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00D6FF endColorstr=#00667A)";
behavior: url(PIE.htc);
}
```

IE8 Loads the JQuery library, but gives me the following errors for the subsequent scripts:

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; InfoPath.3; MS-RTC LM 8; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Wed, 28 Nov 2012 19:14:30 UTC

Message: Access is denied.

Line: 4
Char: 12115
Code: 0
URI: file://**PATH**/prototype/js/libs/modernizr-2.0.6.min.js

Message: Access is denied.

Line: 6
Char: 2747
Code: 0
URI:file://**PATH**/prototype/js/respond.min.js

Message: Access is denied to: file://**PATH**/prototype/PIE.htc
Line: 0
Char: 0
Code: 0
URI: file://**PATH**/prototype/index.html

Any idea how to resolve this so that IE loads Modernizr and accepts the PIE.htc reference?

Comment: If you're using PIE, get rid of the ms filter.

Comment: I'll try that on the next iteration to test if that's the issue conflicting the .htc file. For now, I've decided to retain the gradient filters and just let the border-radii degrade in IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided for the time being, I will just let the border-radii degrade in IE since I have to move forward with this prototype to meet deadline. I do plan on taking Diodeus' suggestion into account on the next iteration, at the very least to see if that's what the issue was.

Comment: Also, even though this doesn't resolve the .htc issue in particular, running the site through a WebMatrix virtual server as admin did get rid of the Access Denied issues. May have just been a permissions conflict.